# Javascript in array then return key

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the ean codes from below array in the `variantCodesObject`. That part I can get working however I'm struggeling to return the `key` from the `variantCodesObject`.

```
cart array
[
  {"ean": "7350038272416","quantity": 1},
  {"ean": "7350038270276","quantity": 3}
]


variantCodesObject array

[
 { 261584049: "7350038272416" },
 { 261583813: "7350038274120" },
 { 261583424: "7350038270276" },
 { 261122928: "210000018685" },
]

cart.forEach(function (cartItem){    
  var ean = cartItem.ean;
  var qty = cartItem.quantity;

  if(variantCodesObject.indexOf(ean)){
    
    makeSomeRequest(??, qty) //How do I get the key of the found EAN's here?

  }

})
```

In above example how do I get for ean `7350038272416` the key value `261584049`?

I tried something like this:

```
variantCodesObject.forEach(function(item){
          if(item.indexOf(ean)){
            Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
              console.log("key:" + key + "value:" + item[key]);
            });
          }
        });
```

But that returns the full `variantCodesObject`.

Comment: Any chance you could modify your `variantCodesObject` array? It could look like this: `[ { id: 261584049, ean: 7350038272416 }...]` and then you could just return the `id`.

Comment: `if(variantCodesObject.indexOf(ean))` makes little sense to begin with, you would be comparing an array with a scalar value here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by checking the value of the object in the `variantCodesObject` against the `.ean` property on each cart item. If it matches, do whatever you'd like with the key

```js
cart = [
  {"ean": "7350038272416","quantity": 1},
  {"ean": "7350038270276","quantity": 3}
]


variantCodesObject = [
 { 261584049: "7350038272416" },
 { 261583813: "7350038274120" },
 { 261583424: "7350038270276" },
 { 261122928: "210000018685" },
]


cart.forEach(item => {
  variantCodesObject.forEach(obj => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (value === item.ean) {
        console.log(key);
      }
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: Excellent! I had sopme sort of the same but did not put it together like you did. Anyway thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use `Array.reduce()` to gather data from the array:

```js
const cart =
[
  {"ean": "7350038272416","quantity": 1},
  {"ean": "7350038270276","quantity": 3}
]


const variantCodesObject =
[
 { 261584049: "7350038272416" },
 { 261583813: "7350038274120" },
 { 261583424: "7350038270276" },
 { 83424: "7350038270276" },
 { 261122928: "210000018685" },
]

cart.forEach(function (cartItem){    
  var ean = cartItem.ean;
  var qty = cartItem.quantity;

  const keys = variantCodesObject.reduce((ret, obj) =>
  {
    for(let key in obj)
      if (obj[key] == ean)
        ret[ret.length] = key;

    return ret;
  }, []);

  console.log(ean, "=", keys);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Reverse Lookup Table". Here is how you can do that.

```js
var cartArray = [
  { ean: '7350038272416', quantity: 1 },
  { ean: '7350038270276', quantity: 3 },
];

var variantCodesObjectArray = [
  { 261584049: '7350038272416' },
  { 261583813: '7350038274120' },
  { 261583424: '7350038270276' },
  { 261122928: '210000018685' },
];

// We are creating a lookup / dictionary by mapping the "EAN" to the "CODE"
var reverMappedCodesObjectArray = {};

variantCodesObjectArray.forEach(function (entry) {
  var key = Object.keys(entry)[0];
  reverMappedCodesObjectArray[entry[key]] = key;
});

cartArray.forEach(function (cartItem) {
  var ean = cartItem.ean;
  var qty = cartItem.quantity;

  console.log(reverMappedCodesObjectArray[ean]);
});
```